# Inject doctrine Entity Manager with Phroute

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, routes

I create my doctrine entitymanager on the connexion.php file.

Controller use the entitymanager to manage the database.

My variable $oGestionnaireEntites becomes null.

There is a way to inject my entity manager on Phroute route ?

```
<?php

require "../configuration/connexion.php";

use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;

session_start();


$oRouteCollector = new RouteCollector();

$oRouteCollector->any('/myapplication/mymobileapplication/{controller}/{action}',     function($sController, $sAction) {
try {
    $sController = ucfirst(strtolower($sController));
    $sClasseControleur = "\controller\Controller" . $sController;

    if (class_exists($sClasseControleur)) {
        //oGestionnaireEntites is NULL
        $oControleur = new $sClasseControleur($oGestionnaireEntites);

        if (method_exists($oControleur, $sAction)) {
            $oControleur->{$sAction}();
        } else {
            $sClasseControleur = get_class($oControleur);
            throw new \Exception("Action $sAction non définie dans la classe $sClasseControleur");
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('la classe nexiste pas');
    }

    return "controlleur $sController action $sAction";
} catch (\Exception $sException) {
    var_dump($sException->getMessage());
}
});
```